# Spring Security and OAuth2 generate token with custom grant type

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using Spring+Oauth2 to secure a web sevice and I've added a custom grant type (custom-grant):

```
<bean id="myTokenGranter" class="com.example.oauth2.MyTokenGranter" />

<oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="client-details-service" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
    <oauth:refresh-token/>
    <oauth:password/>
    <oauth:custom-grant token-granter-ref="myTokenGranter" />
</oauth:authorization-server>
```

Spring calls implementation just fine. However I don't know how I should actually generate a token here. I see that they use a class called "RandomValueStringGenerator" but I'm not sure if there's no better way, moreover I don't know how to generate a "good" token as how long it should be or if spring checks the token's uniqueness actually etc. Is there a way I can call Spring's own generator part here?

Here is my tokengranter class now:

```
public class MyTokenGranter implements TokenGranter {

private RandomValueStringGenerator generator = new RandomValueStringGenerator();

@Override
public OAuth2AccessToken grant(String grantType, TokenRequest tokenRequest) {
    //...logic added here later
    return new DefaultOAuth2AccessToken(generator.generate());
}
```

}

I can't find a good example of this and there is only a half-implemented test tokengranter in spring ouath2 sources.

Comment: Also there is org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.AbstractTokenGranter I could extend but I don't know how to pass the constructor params in my xml config?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so this can be done with `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.AbstractTokenGranter` actually, either by copying it or trying to pass the proper constructors. I just post it for anyone who has the same problem. You can also extend `AbstractTokenGranter` but I failed to pass the proper constructors

**Here is my implementation:**

```
public class MyTokenGranter implements TokenGranter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthorizationServerTokenServices tokenService;

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;
    
    @Autowired
    private DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory defaultOauth2RequestFactory;
    
    private String grantType;
    
    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken grant(String grantType, TokenRequest tokenRequest) {
        if (!this.grantType.equals(grantType)) {
            return null;
        }
        String clientId = tokenRequest.getClientId();
        ClientDetails client = clientDetailsService.loadClientByClientId(clientId);
        validateGrantType(grantType, client);
        return getAccessToken(client, tokenRequest);
    }
    
    protected OAuth2AccessToken getAccessToken(ClientDetails client, TokenRequest tokenRequest) {
        return tokenService.createAccessToken(getOAuth2Authentication(client, tokenRequest));
    }
    
    protected OAuth2Authentication getOAuth2Authentication(ClientDetails client, TokenRequest tokenRequest) {
        OAuth2Request storedOAuth2Request = defaultOauth2RequestFactory.createOAuth2Request(client, tokenRequest);
        return new OAuth2Authentication(storedOAuth2Request, null);
    }
    
    protected void validateGrantType(String grantType, ClientDetails clientDetails) {
        Collection<String> authorizedGrantTypes = clientDetails.getAuthorizedGrantTypes();
        if (authorizedGrantTypes != null && !authorizedGrantTypes.isEmpty()
                && !authorizedGrantTypes.contains(grantType)) {
            throw new InvalidClientException("Unauthorized grant type: " + grantType);
        }
    }

    public String getGrantType() {
        return grantType;
    }

    public void setGrantType(String grantType) {
        this.grantType = grantType;
    }
}
```

**Xml config:**

```
<bean id="myTokenGranter" class="com.example.MyTokenGranter">
  <property name="grantType" value="custom-grant" />
</bean>
<oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetailsService" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
    <oauth:refresh-token/>
    <oauth:password/>
    <oauth:custom-grant token-granter-ref="myTokenGranter" />
</oauth:authorization-server>
```

Comment: I know this is super old so this is a long shot. But any chance you know how to create my own Granter that will OVERRIDE one that Spring is providing? I want to create my own Client Credentials granter. I can't figure it out.

Comment: Sorry, I have long gone from this project or Spring in general

Comment: Figured. Was worth a shot. What have you moved on it, from spring? Just curious

Comment: Well I'm a CTO at a company now, so I work on many things at once, but we do use spring (boot) too. Back then I went on to do Android/IOS development for a couple of years. Nothing wrong with Spring, we just use annotation based config now.

Comment: Congrats on the upgrade. I use annotation based and Java Config for my Spring Boot stuff. I've been neck deep in Java for 20+ years just wondering what people move on to technology wise

Answer (score 0):

More just an FYI but the constructor-arg can be used if you extend the AbstractTokenGranter. For example:

```
public class MyTokenGranter extends AbstractTokenGranter
{
    private static final String GRANT_TYPE = "custom-grant";

    protected MyTokenGranter(
            AuthorizationServerTokenServices tokenServices,
            ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService )
    {
        super( tokenServices, clientDetailsService, GRANT_TYPE );
    }

    @Override
    protected OAuth2Authentication getOAuth2Authentication(AuthorizationRequest clientToken) 
    {
        throw new RuntimeException( "Not implemented" );
    }
}
```

and

```
<bean id="myTokenGranter" class="com.example.MyTokenGranter">
    <constructor-arg ref="tokenServices"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetailsService"/>
</bean>
```